# how to fix error "Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views."

Tags: java, android, android-studio

i wanted to refresh my timer on screen every second. i got this error and can't fix it.

i tried using handlers and runOnUiThreat but none worked.

```
 runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            final Timer txtRefresher = new Timer();

            txtRefresher.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    timerConfirmation.setText(String.format("%d", timer));

                    if (timer == 0) {
                        txtRefresher.cancel();
                    }
                }
            }, 199, 60000);
        }
    });
```

i expect to change the view and UI without any error and also i want to change it every second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `postDelayed()` on some `View` in your UI. This sample activity shows a `Toast` every 5000 milliseconds:

```
/***
  Copyright (c) 2012 CommonsWare, LLC
  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not
  use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy
  of the License at http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0. Unless required
  by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the
  License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS
  OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the specific
  language governing permissions and limitations under the License.

  Covered in detail in the book _The Busy Coder's Guide to Android Development_
    https://commonsware.com/Android
 */

package com.commonsware.android.post;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class PostDelayedDemo extends Activity implements Runnable {
  private static final int PERIOD=5000;
  private View root=null;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    root=findViewById(android.R.id.content);
  }

  @Override
  public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    run();
  }

  @Override
  public void onStop() {
    root.removeCallbacks(this);

    super.onStop();
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
    Toast.makeText(PostDelayedDemo.this, "Who-hoo!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
         .show();
    root.postDelayed(this, PERIOD);
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks a million! i used PostDelayed and it solved my problem.